# Динамическое изменение размера шрифта TextView в xml-ресурсе

Tags: android, android-layout

Возникла проблема при работе со шрифтом. Есть ли возможность, в зависимости от количества слов менять размер шрифта, не программно, а прямо в `xml` ?

```
   <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/titleDescription"
        android:layout_width="196dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayoutTop"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/progressbar"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="20.5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20.5dp"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Rihanna Love the way"
            android:textColor="@color/colorFontBlue"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:singleLine="false"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/title"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:text="Just gona stand there and ..."
            android:textColor="#535353"
            android:textSize="15dip"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Если вы расскажите, какая именно у вас проблема со шрифтами и почему никак нельзя программно, то возможно вам предложат более правильное решение вашей проблемы, чем просто - нет, так нельзя сделать

Comment: @pavlofff  меня интересуют не только шрифты, а в целом адаптивность дизайна. Отделаться одним xml-ем в данной ситуации я так понял не выйдет. Я скорее всего не с той стороны зашел, наверное, надо еще почитать документацию...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, в нативном SDK нельзя. xml-ресурсы статичны.

Хотя вот в новой библиотеке от Google - [Data Binding Library](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/data-binding/guide.html) в xml-ресурсе можно прописать некоторую логику, например  в xml-языке этой библиотеки присутствует тернарный оператор , логические операторы и есть возможность вызова методов прямо из xml-ресурса, так что в этом случае вполне возможно.

Но проще и быстрее будет все же сделать все это динамически, через православный java-код.

Comment: Интересная информация, большое спасибо. Эта штука обещает невероятные ништяки.

Comment: @nekaneka согласен, пока есть одна большая проблема - биндинг одностороний, обещают решить со временем, тогда точно уже программирование под андроид не будет таким, как прежде. Особенно в паре с rxAndroid.

Comment: @pavlofff как по мне большая проблема это отсутствие поддержки со стороны системы рефакторинга, для больших проектов это довольно важно ибо при переименовании какого-нибудь id легко забыть или не заметить что где то он используется через биндинги, а всплыть это может уже только при глубоком UI тестировании...

Comment: @xkor В позавчерашнем релизе [AS 2.0 P5](https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/recent/androidstudio20preview5available) уже началась работа по интеграции этой библиотеки в IDE - сейчас сделали автокомплит для этой либы при работе с xml. Думаю со временем библиотека будет полностью интегрирована в IDE